# Simple Graph Theory Terminology

Tags: data-structures, graph-theory

I'm just starting out to learn the basics of graph theory, and my textbook is a little unclear about a simple concept. The term "adjacency" as far as I understand, given a undirected graph, if A and B nodes are connected, A is adjacent to B, and B is adjacent to A. I was wondering if this was still true given a directed graph where A points to B?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like it was pretty well explained, but to provide some visuals. Adjacent edges are two nodes that are connected, and there are two basic setups:

In an undirected graph, two nodes A and B connected by an edge are adjacent to each other

[image: undirected graph]

In a directed graph, two nodes A and B connected by an edge **from** A **to** B means that you can get to B from A (or, B **is adjacent to** A):

[image: directed graph]

Answer (score 0):

In a directed graph where A points to B, `{A,B}` would be included in the graph's adjacency list and `{B,A}` would not be. That is, A is adjacent to B, but not vice-versa.

Answer (score 0):

In a digraph, there is an edge from `v1` to `v2`, then **`v2` is adjacent to `v1`**. (From `v1` to `v2` as in `v2` is the head and `v1` is the tail.)

In an undirected graph this is symmetric - if `v2` is adjacent to `v1` then `v1` is also adjacent to `v2`, and we say `v1 ~ v2`.

In a digraph, `v1` may not necessarily also be adjacent to `v2`, so we say `v1 ↓ v2`.

EDIT: also, you could try asking this sort of question on the [CSTheory Stackexchange](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/) site in the future - you might get better answers.

Comment: When you say there is an edge from v1 to v2, does that mean v1 points to v2 or v2 points to v1?

Comment: v1 points to v2, i.e. v1 is the tail and v2 is the head (answer updated accordingly)